# How can I standardize names in Python using a dictionary map?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a LOT of survey results data, and one column asked for which state the user was from. For example, some people wrote "VA" and others wrote "Virginia"

I was hoping to use a dictionary map, but things weren't working out so well. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? I am relatively new to Python, so I'm still trying to get the hang of things.

Here's what I've tried:

```
abv = {"Virginia": "VA", "Maryland": "MD",
      "West Virginia": "WV", "Pennsylvania": "PA"}
abv2 = dict(map(reversed, abv.items()))
survey['New State'] = survey.State.map(abv2)
survey
```

Some people typed "Virginia" and others wrote "VA". I only want the abbreviation version.

Comment: can u put ur data and code

Comment: try libpostal python library to mark them

Comment: @xiutiqianshi posted in question

Comment: next time add the `pandas` tag from the beginning, to avoid wasting people's time

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time that is the case @Pynchia ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your DataFrame looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd                                                         
>>> survey = pd.DataFrame( 
...     ["Virginia", "VA", "VA", "Penns.", "PA", "Pennsylvania"], 
...     columns=["State"] 
... )                                                                           
>>> survey                                                                      
          State
0      Virginia
1            VA
2            VA
3        Penns.
4            PA
5  Pennsylvania
```

The initial mapping you construct can be a mapping of longer-form names to the canonical abbreviations.

```
>>> to_abbrev = { 
...     "Virginia": "VA", 
...     "Pennsylvania": "PA", 
...     "Penns.": "PA", 
... }
```

Then, update that with the abbreviations themselves:

```
>>> to_abbrev.update({v: v for v in to_abbrev.values()})          
>>> to_abbrev                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
{'Virginia': 'VA',
 'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
 'Penns.': 'PA',
 'VA': 'VA',
 'PA': 'PA'}
```

Finally, call `.map()` to get the result:

```
>>> survey["State"].map(to_abbrev)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
0    VA
1    VA
2    VA
3    PA
4    PA
5    PA
Name: State, dtype: object
```

It's worth stating the semi-obvious: your `to_abbrev` must be a *complete* mapping; otherwise, missing values will be NaN:

```
>>> survey.append({"State": "Wisconsin"}, ignore_index=True)["State"].map(to_abbrev)                                                                                                                                                                         
0     VA
1     VA
2     VA
3     PA
4     PA
5     PA
6    NaN
Name: State, dtype: object
```

As suggested in the comments, there are undoubtedly libraries out there designed to build this mapping for you more wholistically, taking into account things such as common typos and small grammatical differences, such as "D.C." versus "DC."

Comment: I tried what you had and I still had "Virginia" and "VA" in my data. ```abv = {"Virginia": "VA", "Maryland": "MD",
      "West Virginia": "WV", "Pennsylvania": "PA"}
abv.update({v: v for v in abv.values()})

survey["State"].map(abv)
survey ```

Comment: I suspect maybe your values have spaces; try `survey["State"].str.strip()` first

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot validate the user input frontend, you could easily use the `get` method of the dictionary, providing a default value as fallback:

```
def fix(user_input):
    mapping = {"Virginia": "VA", "Maryland": "MD",
               "West Virginia": "WV", "Pennsylvania": "PA"}

    return mapping.get(user_input, user_input)

print(fix("Virginia"))  # >> VA
print(fix("VA"))  # >> VA
```